# is study or was study or studied

Tags: grammar

if I have a study  in the university on one subject and in the first page of my study I have to identify or summarize of the study.
Can i say?
The study is about the committer of major crime.
or
The study was about the committer of major crime.
My question which is correct to use, past or present tense?

Answer (score 1):

Is the study ongoing, or have you finished it? If the study is ongoing, then you should use present tense. If the study is over, you may use past or present tense-- your choice. This is because the study still exists, and it is still about the same material. You have also already finished with the study, so it can be referred to in the past tense if you would like.

This isn't a part of your question, but a quick note: your sentence can flow a little bit better if, instead of saying "the committer of major crime," you say "criminal." Criminal is a widely accepted word for someone who has committed a crime, and it sounds more natural in English.